# Why doesn't a wire mesh render?

Tags: rendering, mesh

I'm working on a simple 2D motion graphics project and I'm trying to use a circle mesh for part of it. However, the circle isn't being rendered:

[image]

The circle should be appearing right where the cursor is, but it's not. Obviously *some* objects are being rendered, as evidenced by those two planes.

I've set up the circle in regards to material exactly the same as I did the two planes, Emission, RGBA 1.0/1.0/1.0/1.0, Strength 2.0, but it's not being rendered. I also noticed that it only shows up as an outline when in the *Material* Viewport Shading mode.

I've tried googling this, but I haven't found anything yet.

What's causing this and how can I get the circle to render, or do I need to go with something else?

[image]

Comment: the circle has no thickness (surface to reflect the light so it can be seen) it can't be rendered like that you have to make it thicker ( like the lines )

Comment: @Chebhou How would I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The circle has **no faces** ( surface to reflect the light so it can be seen ) it can't be rendered like that. You have to make it 'thicker'. For that :

- In *Object Mode* select the circle and switch to *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
- Hold  <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right-click on the circle ( to select it all vertices )
- Press <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> ( extrude and resize )
- Move the mouse till you get the desired result

[image]

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness you're welcome